# AWS S3 CDK Python Bucket replication configuration

Tags: python, amazon-s3, replication, aws-cdk

I'm using CDK python to create and S3 bucket and a replication.configuration across a region

I keep getting an error when I synth:

Value did not match any type in union

here is my code for the rules section of my s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationConfigurationProperty:

Can someone check out my code for the source selection area. I think that is where the issue is:

```
        self.replication_conf = s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationConfigurationProperty(
            role=new_role_arn,
            rules=[
                s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationRuleProperty(
                    id='replicate-all-rule',
                    destination=some_arn,
                    status='Enabled',
                    source_selection_criteria = s3.CfnBucket.SseKmsEncryptedObjectsProperty(
                       status='Enabled'
                    )
                )         
            ]
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your syntax is simply incorrect.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationRuleProperty.html) the `source_selection_criteria` should be of type `SourceSelectionCriteriaProperty`. It is that property that holds the `SseKmsEncryptedObjectsProperty`. Presumably this is correct (although it is untested):

```py
self.replication_conf = s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationConfigurationProperty(
  role=new_role_arn,
  rules=[
    s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationRuleProperty(
      id='replicate-all-rule',
      destination=some_arn,
      status='Enabled',
      source_selection_criteria=s3.CfnBucket.SourceSelectionCriteriaProperty(
        sse_kms_encrypted_objects=s3.CfnBucket.SseKmsEncryptedObjectsProperty(
            status='Enabled'
          )
        )
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: really appreciate the answer. It actually works now. I had another issue with my "destination", but I managed to fix it... Really really appreciate the help